# Sticking a floating div to the current position of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a ul with li's that has a scroll bar on it.

In other words you can only see 8 list items at a time however you can scroll through them.

Each li is editable. When you click the li button a div appears to the right of it. (menu/options)

My problem is the div appears only on the orignal location of the li and not the current position of the li.

How can I make it so the div(menu/option) always appears to the right of the selected li?

Edit: I tried using jsfiddle however I couldn't get Jquery to work on it(I'm not too familiar with jsfiddle)

Here are an example of what is happening

First :

[image]

Second :

[image]

The First image shows what it is supposed to do. However when you scroll using the scrollbar the next time you click "edit" the div(menu) popups in the wrong spot. (see 2nd image)

Comment: Please share the code with us, best if you could put it into http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Alright, I'm throwing together an example real quick.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I mocked up based on what you wrote, but I hope you get the idea on how to achieve it. The main concept is to make the main-menu item `position:relative` and its sub-munu items `position:absolute`.

http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/FzKvb/

If you can edit your html, this could be achieved with css alone.

Answer (score 1):

Your floating div should be absolutely positioned and it should be inside your `<li>`.  You need to make sure your `<li>` tags do not have static position, but relative or absolute.  That should solve your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jx3c5/

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="floaterThing"><input type="text"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
#floaterThing{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;    
    top: 0;
}
#box{
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:scroll;        
}
li{
    position:relative;
    width:25px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    var target = $(this),
        targetWidth = target.width();

   target.append($('#floaterThing'));
    $('#floaterThing').show().css('left', targetWidth+'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with absolute and relative positioning.

Basically, I have an outer div that contains the whole menu that is scrollable in both directions (using `overflow: auto`). Inside that I have the menu container that holds the `<li>` elements.

The li elements are styled with relative position.

When an li is clicked, another div `.menu` is added to them. That div is absolutely positioned to the right of the li so that when it scrolls, it maintains its position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".container > li").click(function(){
        $(".container li .menu").remove();

        $(".container > li.selected").removeClass("selected");

        $(this).append("<div class='menu'>");
        $(this).find(".menu").append("<li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li>");

        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNPk/2/)

---

In the example, I append the menu onClick, however, you could use a pre-created menu and just show it using `.show()` onClick.